# The 'ProviderPackage' package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I installed Visual Studio 2012 and at a later date Update 2. After installing Update 2, when I load any project, I get the following error:

> --------------------------- 
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 
>   ---------------------------  
>   The 'ProviderPackage' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
>
> Continue to show this error message? 
>       --------------------------- 
>       Yes   No 
>       ---------------------------

After locating the `ActivityLog.xml`, I see the following set of errors:

```
<entry>
    <record>300</record>
    <time>2013/04/23 18:32:54.002</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [ProviderPackage]</description>
    <guid>{5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}</guid>
</entry>
<entry>
    <record>301</record>
    <time>2013/04/23 18:32:54.012</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [ProviderPackage]</description>
    <guid>{5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}</guid>
    <hr>80131522</hr>
    <errorinfo>Method 'GetHostedIntellisenseTypes' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.DTEWrapperCached' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphProviderPackage, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an implementation.</errorinfo>
</entry>
<entry>
    <record>302</record>
    <time>2013/04/23 18:32:54.012</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [ProviderPackage]</description>
    <guid>{5F2E5E42-4192-4D79-A0D8-1D881E808829}</guid>
    <hr>80131522</hr>
    <errorinfo>Method 'GetHostedIntellisenseTypes' in type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.DTEWrapperCached' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.GraphProviderPackage, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not have an implementation.</errorinfo>
```

Google searches do not reveal an exact match on my issue. I've tried searching the packages on the install ISO and cannot locate a package that needs to be repaired...

```
F:\packages>dir /s *provider*
 Volume in drive F is VS2012_ULT_MSDN_ENU
 Volume Serial Number is 4A21-C8BD

 Directory of F:\packages\SSDT

   07/26/2012  11:30 AM           780,288 DbSqlPackageProvider.msi
               1 File(s)        780,288 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               1 File(s)        780,288 bytes
               0 Dir(s)               0 bytes free
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was having the same issue and repairing my SQL Data Tools and related seems to have cleared that up for me.

Comment: Yep, worked for me, thanks. I repaired everything after vs2012 that had a repair option that was in any way related to vs2012 (mainly sql stuff).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**This is Aaron's (Aaron Reed) answer from above, just copied as an answer instead of part of the question:**

Fixed it... *Fixed it...* Fixed it...

1. Opened Programs and Features (run: appwiz.cpl)
2. Sorted list of installed apps by: Install Date
3. Filtered list by adding "SQL" to the upper right search filter
4. List item

I installed VS2012 on 4/1/13, so I went through each listed SQL item in the list, and right click --> Repair

From there I ran VS2012 and opened the target Solution file without issue.

My list:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier App Framework
- Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - enu (11.1.20627.00)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Objects (x64)
- Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012 (x64)
- Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Objects
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL Compiler Service
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Command Line Utilities
- Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools Build Utilities - enu (11.1.206...
- Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Language Service
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier App Framework
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL SpriptDom

Comment: I had a very similar problem with an error 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.PythonTools' and this method fixed it for me

Comment: I was hoping I could add a comment like, "WOW Can't believe this still works for VS2015", but it appears not... At least for me that is.

Answer (score 106):

- Close Visual Studio.
- Open a Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2012 (as administrator).
- Type `devenv /setup`.
- Restart Visual Studio.

Possible duplicate of *[Visual Studio 2012 error: Package 'Visual C++ package' failed to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819613/vs2012-error-package-visual-c-package-failed-to-load)*

See *[Visual C++ package: failed to load?????](http://happyivyli.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/visual-c-package-failed-to-load.html)*

Comment: Thanks for this tip! Also, running `devenv /resetuserdata` can help if the first command does not.

Comment: 'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Tibor, please check that you opened a Developer `cmd` prompt (try the All Programs in the Start Menu).  This adds `devenv` (and other useful things) to the path, which aren't present by default.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem is VS 2012 express version doesn't have devenv.exe

Comment: @Tibor You could try `...\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe /setup`   (At your own risk as I haven't properly tested it!)

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it threw an error before, so I skipped. Now I tried it again and my project actually loads :)

Comment: Worked for me on VS2013.

Comment: /setup and /resetuserdata worked for me as well, except after doing it I got a different message pointing to Telerik Controls for WPF. WHen i repaired the telerik installation everything worked fine.

Comment: No dice for me with VS2013 :-/ I'll try some more solutions on this page.

Comment: Easy fix for VS2013 Express.  However, devenv is called WDExpress.exe in Express version.  Thus, 'WDExpress.exe /setup' fixed the issue.

Answer (score 31):

This worked for me -

In order to fix the issue one needs to clear the Visual Studio cache under:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache
```

Thanks go to blog post *[SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]](http://kuebiko.blogspot.in/2013/07/setsite-failed-for-package.html)*.

Comment: That worked for me - but remember to clear the cache of the right VS version (I had several installed and on my first try I cleared the wrong one)

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Usually this can be fixed by clearing the Visual Studio cache under:

Visual Studio 2012: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache`

Visual Studio 2013: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache`

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this by uninstalling or removing:

Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - enu (14.0.50325.0)

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 5):

An even quicker fix is to simply repair the Microsoft SQL Server  in the list. That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me. 
Window7 SP1 + VS 2013
Open a Developer Command Propmpt for VS 2012 (as administrator).
Run devenv /setup.

Comment: For what it's worth, I only started having this issue _after_ installing VS2013 (and Update 1). `devenv /setup` worked great.

Comment: One note: run the Developer Command Prompt for VS2013 as Administrator

Comment: why do you give the same answer as steve?

Answer (score 3):

Uninstalling/Repairing SQL Server Data tools is the only thing which worked for me, thanks to *wayne.blackmon* comment.

Picture below

[image: Uninstall SQL Server Data tools]

Comment: Repair should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2013 for Windows 8.1.

The previous answers didn't work for me. I had to repair Visual Studio and then reboot my machine.

Comment: When this has happened to me in the past, that was the only solution that worked for me too. I'm trying out some of the other ones on this post, but all have struck out so far. **Update**: This worked http://stackoverflow.com/a/30218921/3543437

Answer (score 2):

For me the `ActivityLog.xml` stated

```
<errorinfo>Access to the path 'C:\Users\Klas\Documents\Visual Studio
2015\ArchitectureExplorer' is denied.</errorinfo>
```

When I examined this folder I realized that the entire folder structure here

```
C:\Users\Klas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015
```

had permission set so that my user had no write permissions. I added Full Control rights to my user for this folder and everything below.

After that, the message went away. Also, when I started Visual Studio it created lots of subfolders to this folder.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem appeared after I installed Visual Studio 2015. From that point nor 2015, nor previous versions of Visual Studio would load.
The problem was the PATH environment variable exceeding the MAX length.

I shortened it to less than 2048 and restarted the machine. Visual Studio started loading, but with some errors still. Lastly run the `devenv /setup`, and all is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error on Visual Studio start up:

`the 'visual studio component model host package' did not load correctly...`

After that bunch of other `The '' package did not load correctly...` error messages.

I realized I don't have enough free space on my C drive, where the Visual Studio were installed.

I opened up some space and restarted the Visual Studio, solved the problem.

Not sure if it has anything to do with the free space on disk though.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar error (on Windows 7. I installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional and then after that, several "...package did not load correctly" messages started showing up when I ran Visual Studio 2012).

What fixed my issue was to repair "Microsoft Studio Tools for Applications 2012".

1. Run "appwiz.cpl" (*Control Panel* → *Programs* → *Uninstall a program*
2. Right-click on "Microsoft Studio Tools for Applications 2012. Select "Change", then click "Repair".

[image: Control Panel - Programs]

After this, I can open up Visual Studio 2012 without those error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error.  After I updated to VS2012.U2, the problem went away. TFS 2012 update 2 can't be removed without removing TFS.  While I had an issue with upgrading from TFS2012.U1 to U2, I have found TFS2012.U2 to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion,

Run as admin, and restart the VS application.

Apply package update.
Reboot.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It was the problem with access rights to my %USERPROFILE% directory (because of the failure with the PC). Setting permissions to full access fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3757edf1-5cef-434c-be6b-0a8ade1a7aad/visualstudio-2012-crash-on-start-driver-common-package-error?forum=visualstudiogeneral):

- Please open Windows Explorer, and navigate to <Visual Studio Installation Path>\Common7\IDE
- Devenv.exe /SafeMode: Launches the IDE in safe mode loading minimal windows.
- Devenv.exe /ResetSettings: Restores the IDE's default settings, optionally resets to the specified VSSettings file.
- Devenv.exe /ResetAddin: Removes commands and command UI associated with the specified Add-in.
- Devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs: Clears all SkipLoading tags added to VSPackages.

If still no help, I suggest you try repairing your Visual Studio installation or uninstall it and then reinstall it. If you want to reinstall it, I am afraid that you need a DVD or a fine Internet.

Doing the first three steps works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got "lucky" and restarted Visual Studio 2013 and it worked. I have had other errors in which deleting the temp cache items cleared it up.

Side note. While Visual Studio 2015 is not perfect as of yet, and NuGet has become less friendly to use IMO, if my computer is restarted by the company domain network administrators OR especially when there is a computer losing power with a brown-out of some loss of power Visual Studio 2013 becomes a bit a "fun" to fix while Visual Studio 2015 projects for months seem to just open just fine as if nothing happened when I login.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solve this problem by removing the Read-only attribute of the folder "Visual Studio 2015" in `<C:\Users\myuser\Documents>`.