# 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlLan......did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have installed the visual studio 2013.after installation and exactly at preparing for first use the following window appeared!!!this window just appeared at first time of use and from then on I did not see this window.is it a serious problem?if yes how can i solve it?
the message of window is:
The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlLanguageServices.Package,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.SqlLanguageServices,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' package did not load correctly.
the problem may have been.....(it is too long..)

Answer (score 2):

This error was happening to me any time I opened VS2013 - Right about when the 'Announcements' filled in the Start Page tab.

Tried installing VS2013 Update 2 - Took forever.  Didn't fix. (TF;DF?)

Did the following based on this answer:
[The 'ProviderPackage' package did not load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176933/the-providerpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly)

1. Opened Programs and Features (run: appwiz.cpl)
2. Right click on 'Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools' and choose 'Repair'

That seemed to do it for me.  Then for good measure, did this as instructed by MS site:

> If you'd like to check for updates manually, open Visual Studio 2013
>   and choose the Tools > Extensions and Updates menu. SQL Server tooling
>   updates will appear in the Updates list.