# Visual Studio won't open

Tags: visual-studio

I just downloaded VisualSVN Server. It seems to have conflicted with Visual Studio, as none of my projects will now open. The error it is throwing up says

> A problem has occurred when loading the Microsoft visual studio menu. To fix this problem, run 'devenv.exe/resetsettings from the command prompt.

I rebooted and am getting this error now:

> The MRU package did not load correctly.

Comment: Did you run 'devenv.exe/resetsettings' from the command prompt yet? Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Yes done both still nothing

Comment: Are you sure Visual SVN server is the problem? Did you try uninstalling it?

Comment: Yes unistalled it and there are no issues. I rebooted again and now  a new error outline in question is coming up

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176933/the-providerpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly

Comment: Still no luck with that workaround either

Comment: I ran into a similar problem where I was getting the `run devenv.exe /resetsettings` type of error message, although in my case, it happened intermittently while trying to run Visual Studio remotely.  I solved the problem by running Visual Studio with the `Run as Administrator` option.

Answer (score 12):

I tried "devenv.exe /setup" as commented, but it completely broke my VS2015.

Then I tried "**devenv.exe /resetuserdata**" and it works now.

Comment: For me this makes the splash screen stay longer but it closes and goes back to closing instantly afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. /resetsettings did not work. This happened to me when I upgraded VS2022 from 17.1 to 17.4

Answer (score 10):

The fix for me was to run visual studio using `./devenv.exe /setup` using a  console session running as Administrator. Running `./devenv.exe /resetsettings` didn't fix the issue for me.

I had this issue and I didn't have Visual SVN installed. Resources online suggested that you should check the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Packages\{2DC9DAA9-7F2D-11d2-9BFC-00C04F9901D1}` and ensure `InprocServer32` is correctly set to the `vslog.dll` file. If it isn't then it suggested running './devenv.exe /setup', however my machine had this correctly set, and running devenv with the setup flag fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this repeatedly in Visual Studio 2015 and it was driving me up the wall.  The /resetsettings option worked, but of course deleted all of my customisations, which was very irritating.

The solution turned out to be a path that was too long.  See:

http://andydunkel.net/coding/2015/11/13/visual_studio_problem_occured.html

My path wasn't 2048 characters but was close, so try removing some unneeded entries from your PATH and it might solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue with VisualSVN 4.0.12 installation in Visual Studio 2013. (Interestingly, my Visual Studio 2012 instance worked just fine, it was only VS 2013 that was affected.) To resolve the issue with VS 2013, I performed the following steps:

1. I unblocked the VisualSVN-4.0.12.msi file that was in my downloads directory.
2. I right-clicked and selected "Repair Installation" from the context menu.
3. I right-clicked my VS 2013 icon and selected "Run as Administrator".
4. VS 2013 started up normally, with no error messages.

I think the key was making sure the that the .msi file was unblocked before performing the installation.

Answer (score 2):

I had the Visual Studio 2019 installed and had the same issue, chkdsk command resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

```
devenv.exe /resetsettings
```

Did not work for me originally. Make sure you run the command prompt as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Open Visual Studio developer Command prompt in Admin mode.

Run `devenv /resetsettings`

It will reset you visual studio default settings(theme, layout) etc.
And not any of the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Run devenv /resetsettings not
i reset my computer and it is opened directly

Answer (score 0):

Run devenv /resetsettings  as Administrator did not work for me.
Running "devenv.exe /resetuserdata" works but you will have to do reconnect to your Azure/Teams which should be straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you are here for Visual Studio "Code", my issue was solved by disabling real-time scanning of my McAfee antivirus. It was actively scanning for any file that executes on the system and hence was slowing the startup of VS code as well as throwing the "window not responding"