# Visual Studio 2013 Professional failed to start

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-2013, ide, windows-8.1

Just installed a fresh Visual Studio 2013 Professional on my machine with Windows 8.1.
The setup was successful but VS failed to start. It's frozen on the splash screen.
[image: VS splash screen]

EDIT:
activityLog.xml

```
<entry>
    <record>23</record>
    <time>2014/12/07 21:32:12.467</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ConnectedUserPackage]</description>
    <guid>{7F679D93-2EB6-47C9-85EB-F6AD16902662}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>24</record>
    <time>2014/12/07 21:32:12.467</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ConnectedUserPackage]</description>
    <guid>{7F679D93-2EB6-47C9-85EB-F6AD16902662}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

Comment: Did you try to disable your anti-virus? Or is there any entry in the event log?

Comment: No antivirus installed yet. I just installed my windows. Where is the log file of the installation?

Comment: Try to start Visual Studio from the command line with the log-Parameter: devenv /log
.A log file called ActivityLog.XML will be created in %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0

Comment: Added the content of the log file.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have a similar issue. Same error in the log.

Comment: I solved this issue, sorry for not posting it. What I remember is that it was a Team Explorer problem or a Team Foundation Server one. Please download https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776 and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921 also upgrade yor IE to v11 and check and install all windows updates regarding visual studio 2013. I'll search for exact answer meanwhile and I'll post it here if I found it.
Don't forget to cleanup VS logs.

Comment: I use GIT not TFS, so I do not really want to install Team Explorer... FYI, how I got here: The errors started after I upgraded to VS2013 Update 4. The white screen started after following the advice of this post plus its first comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19428110/371917

Comment: Oh, and is there a call to clean the VS logs, as you mention?

Comment: Installing VS2013 Team Explorer added the missing file. (I suppose you can add your comment as the answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing Visual Studio 2013 Team Explorer ( https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776 ) solved the problem.

**EDIT (from comments)**

It may also help to first install the latest version of Visual Studio (currently VS 2013 Update 4, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921 ), and install any related Windows updates.