# Visual Studio 2012 refuses to open projects:

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Here is the relevant part of the log:

```
  <entry>
    <record>208</record>
    <time>2015/03/05 15:17:30.233</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Visual C++ Language Manager Package]</description>
    <guid>{8C2EA640-ABC1-11D0-9D62-00C04FD9DFD9}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>No exports were found that match the constraint: 
    ContractName    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Operations.ITextSearchService
    RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Operations.ITextSearchService</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>209</record>
    <time>2015/03/05 15:17:30.233</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Visual C++ Language Manager Package]</description>
    <guid>{8C2EA640-ABC1-11D0-9D62-00C04FD9DFD9}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>No exports were found that match the constraint: 
    ContractName    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Operations.ITextSearchService
    RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Operations.ITextSearchService</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

I attempted removing all microsoft producst (VS2012, VS2008, SQL server), updating Windows 7 and installing again - same error.

The error materializes after trying to open a project, generated by [RackAFX](http://www.willpirkle.com/rackafx/downloads/). The installation was previously working (read: I had opened and compiled projects via the RAckAFX and VS2012 workflow).

What could it be? I tried:

[vs2012 error: package 'visual c++ package' failed to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819613/vs2012-error-package-visual-c-package-failed-to-load)
[The 'ProviderPackage' package did not load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176933/the-providerpackage-package-did-not-load-correctly)
[Visual Studio 2012 Express only works once](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/c9cc2e43-a1aa-4b64-9c00-f873407344f4/visual-studio-2012-express-only-works-once)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I installed VS2010 and everything just worked fine ... for now.

Answer (score 0):

I could be that you have an old MSBuild.exe (v4) ahead of a newer (v12?) MSBuild.exe. That happened to me before I discovered what MS has made.
From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh162058.aspx:

> MSBuild is now installed as part of Visual Studio rather than as part of the .NET Framework...

So for me, it used to be here:

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe

After installing Build-Tools for VStudio (as part of VS2013 and/or from the "MSBuild Download" link in above URL), it ended up here:

> f:\ProgramFiler-x86\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe

BUT after my old v4 MSbuild.exe. Swapping the PATHs fixed that. (since I'm not sure removing `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\` from the PATH is a good idea just yet).